# English idiom for "Schluss mit Lustig"?

Tags: translation, german-to-english, phrase-request

I was wondering how to best translate the German idiom "Schluss mit Lustig" which means something like "now it's serious, I'm not fooling around anymore".

I read on some wiki that "the party's over" can be used, but looking that up it seems it that it doesn't really fit.

If there is an common idiom that would mean the same thing? I can always straight up translate it, but an idiom would be better.

Comment: [Leo](https://dict.leo.org/german-english/schluss+mit+lustig) forum discussions recommend (scroll to the bottom) "party is over" as well, or "no more Mr Nice Guy". Guess it depends on the context what fits better.

Comment: I would simply say *but seriously now*.

Answer (score 1):

> If there is an common idiom that would mean the same thing?

---

> > OK let's get serious now!

Seems to be the best translation for me.

Comment: That's too long, IMO. I prefer something like "But seriously now, do you really think ...".